# Need to know capabilities of a package C#

Tags: c#, mysql, documentation

Is there a way to know all the capabilities of a package in C#. What I'm trying to do is use MySql.Data package but I have no idea what it's capable of, like what functions it has, how to use them and so on... I've tried browsing but found nothing, neither documentation for this specific package, nor a way to see the code of a package.

I tried searching the web for some answers but found nothing useful and also what I noticed is only with this package, which I think is widely used, I get this kind of troubles, like no info at all or very little of it. Like nobody's using MySQL in C#, that's really odd...

Comment: I *believe* this is https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net ? and is fully documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/ - note I had to google this a little; *usually* package authors do a better job of linking etc - *usually* the trick is to click the "Project website" or "Source repository" link in NuGet, and go from there - but MySql.Data doesn't have a "Source repository" registered, and the "Project website" link isn't helpful. I would file an issue on the github repo suggesting they improve this, but: they don't have issues enabled :(

Comment: If this is a package on nuget, click "Open in NuGet package explorer" on the right to see all classes. But, nothing beats good documentation, and that's normally separate to the code. If it's a third-party package check the github repo for a link to the docs; if it's Microsoft, it's normally bundled on learn.microsoft.com

Comment: This maybe what you are looking for : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/

Comment: @PaulF this looks like it, thanks! Still that's really strange that you can barely find any info on that, it's not some noname package, this one's used quite often. Like I'm back to 2000s)

Comment: @thinkyouretuff: I have been using the package for several years now. I just googled "_MySql.Data.MySqlClient documentation_" & it was easy to find from there - "_MySql.Data.MySqlClient_" is what is shown as the package description on the nugets package. It does take you to a high-level overview to start with, but it does have a link to the detailed information. It could be easier, but once you know the MySQL website, it's not too hard to locate things.